# postgresql 42803: la columna «xxxxx.xxxxxx» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer una consulta y que me lo ordene por cierto campo, sin embargo em resulta error. La consulta a continuación

```sql
SELECT "PROJECT" FROM "REALESTATE.AffectationQuality" WHERE "EFFECTIVETODATE" >= '2018-01-01' group by "INTERNALCODEID";
```

El error a continuación:

```
ERROR:  la columna «REALESTATE.AffectationQuality.PROJECT» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
LINE 1: SELECT "PROJECT" FROM "REALESTATE.AffectationQuality" WHERE ...
               ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Solo estás seleccionando la columna `project`, sin embargo estás intentando agrupar el resultado por `internalcodeid` que ni siquiera forma parte de la consulta.

Imagino que lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
SELECT INTERNALCODEID,PROJECT FROM "REALESTATE.AffectationQuality" WHERE "EFFECTIVETODATE" >= '2018-01-01' group by INTERNALCODEID,PROJECT;
```

Comment: Excelente, ya me funcionó...muchas gracias por la ayuda